# DataTables Custom Search Filter that doesn't interfere with built in Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, datatable

I have a HTML Table that I'm applying DataTables to that I want the user to be able to search, using the built-in search filter, but also a dropdown that filters the data in only ONE specific column AND that doesn't conflict with each other.

What I have right now (probably not the best way) uses the .search() API, and when I use the filter, it works, but when I enter in any thing to the built-in search, it overwrites that filter.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="searchResults" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" width="700">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="td-checkbox"></th>
                <th class="td-currentlyUsed"></th>
                <th class="td-osfNumber"></th>
                <th class="td-title">Title</th>
                <th class="td-titleSort">Title Sort</th>
                <th class="td-popularity">Popularity</th>
                <th class="td-contributor">Contributor</th>
                <th class="td-format">Format</th>
                <th class="td-worldSellable"></th>
                <th class="td-releaseDate">Release Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="itemIds" value="true"></td>
                <td class="td-currentlyUsed"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Currently Used"></i></td>
                <td class="td-osfNumber"></td>
                <td class="td-title">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewModal" data-title="Item Name" data-contrib="Item Contributor" class="previewLink">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span class="item-name">Item Name</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-titleSort">Item Title</td>
                <td class="td-popularity">01</td>
                <td class="td-contributor">Item Contributor</td>
                <td class="td-format">Format Abbreviation</td>
                <td class="td-worldSellable">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe fa-icon fa-true" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="World Sellable"></i><span class="span-worldSellable">worldwide-sellable</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-releaseDate"><span class="item-date">Date Added</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="itemIds" value="true"></td>
                <td class="td-currentlyUsed"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Currently Used"></i></td>
                <td class="td-osfNumber"></td>
                <td class="td-title">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewModal" data-title="Item Name" data-contrib="Item Contributor" class="previewLink">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span class="item-name">Item Name</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-titleSort">Item Title</td>
                <td class="td-popularity">02</td>
                <td class="td-contributor">Item Contributor</td>
                <td class="td-format">Format Abbreviation</td>
                <td class="td-worldSellable"></td>
                <td class="td-releaseDate"><span class="item-date">Date Added</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="itemIds" value="true"></td>
                <td class="td-currentlyUsed"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Currently Used"></i></td>
                <td class="td-osfNumber"></td>
                <td class="td-title">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewModal" data-title="Item Name" data-contrib="Item Contributor" class="previewLink">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span class="item-name">Item Name</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-titleSort">Item Title</td>
                <td class="td-popularity">03</td>
                <td class="td-contributor">Item Contributor</td>
                <td class="td-format">Format Abbreviation</td>
                <td class="td-worldSellable">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe fa-icon fa-true" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="World Sellable"></i><span class="span-worldSellable">worldwide-sellable</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-releaseDate"><span class="item-date">Date Added</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="td-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="itemIds" value="true"></td>
                <td class="td-currentlyUsed"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Currently Used"></i></td>
                <td class="td-osfNumber"></td>
                <td class="td-title">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewModal" data-title="Item Name" data-contrib="Item Contributor" class="previewLink">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Preview"></i>
                    </a>
                    <span class="item-name">Item Name</span>
                </td>
                <td class="td-titleSort">Item Title</td>
                <td class="td-popularity">04</td>
                <td class="td-contributor">Item Contributor</td>
                <td class="td-format">Format Abbreviation</td>
                <td class="td-worldSellable"></td>
                <td class="td-releaseDate"><span class="item-date">Date Added</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var searchResults = $("#searchResults").DataTable({
        "pageLength": 15,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": true,
        "dom": '<"top"fp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "<<", // This is the link to the first page
                "sPrevious": "<", // This is the link to the previous page
                "sNext": ">", // This is the link to the next page
                "sLast": ">>", // This is the link to the last page
            }
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [0, 1, 8],
            "orderable": false
        },
        {
            "targets": [2, 4, 5],
            "visible": false
        }],
        "order": [[2, "asc"]],
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
            $(".dataTables_wrapper .top").addClass("row");
            $(".dataTables_wrapper .bottom").addClass("row");
            $(".dataTables_wrapper .top .dataTables_filter").addClass("col-xs-4");
            $(".dataTables_wrapper .top .dataTables_paginate").addClass("col-xs-12");
            $(".dataTables_wrapper .top .dataTables_filter input").addClass("form-control input-sm");
            $(".dataTables_wrapper .bottom .dataTables_info").addClass("col-xs-6");
            $(".dataTables_wrapper .bottom .dataTables_paginate").addClass("col-xs-6");

            var htmlWF = "<div id='worldwide_filter' class='worldwide_filter col-xs-4'><div class='form-group'><label>Filter By: </label><select id='select_worldwide' name='select_worldwide' class='form-control input-sm'><option value=''>ALL</option><option value='worldwide-sellable'>WORLDWIDE SELLABLE</option></select></div></div>";
            var htmlSB = "<div id='dataTables_sortby' class='dataTables_sortby col-xs-4'><div class='form-group'><label>Sort By: </label><select id='select_sortby' name='select_sortby' class='form-control input-sm'><option value='4'>TITLE</option><option value='9'>RELEASE DATE</option><option value='5'>POPULARITY</option><option value='2'>OSF NUMBER</option></select></div></div>";

            $(htmlWF).insertBefore( "#searchResults_wrapper #searchResults_filter" );
            $(htmlSB).insertAfter( "#searchResults_wrapper #worldwide_filter" );
         }
    });

    $( "#select_worldwide" ).change(function() {
      searchResults.search( this.value ).draw();
    });

});
```

The table is rendering as instructed. I have omitted the element functions that do not pertain to this issue. I am only focusing on the built-in search AND the **`#select_worldwide`** dropdown that are overwriting each other.

Is there a better way to filter out data with a select dropdown from an onChange jQuery call than using the .search() API?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to replace

```
searchResults.search( this.value ).draw();
```

with

```
searchResults.columns(8).search( this.value ).draw();
```

I am specifying the column that holds the worldwide data, and with that added, I can use the search filter in tandem, and neither conflicts with the other.